# Hidding some of the output of ls -l

Tags: rsync, ls, ownership

The output of ls -lht is

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.6G Jan  3 05:32 vServer.log
```

When running `ls -lht` can I add in something that will only show size, mod date and file name?

```
1.6G Jan  3 05:32 vServer.log
```

**Use:**
I'm backing up files from **liveserver** to **backupserver** via rsync, but I want to compare the directories to see if there if there is a new file on **liveserver** before running rsync, so I can send an email alert if there is no new file.

Comment: It runs daily, and I'm currently storing yesterdays output of ls -lht in a file called **backup.var**. I thought there might be a 'cleaner' way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want

```
1.6G Jan  3 05:32 vServer.log
```

from

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.6G Jan  3 05:32 vServer.log
```

then you could use awk to remove the first four columns.

```
ls -lht vServer.log | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: 3 quality and usable answers but this one is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to compare difference in files and directories between live and backup servers, you can try rsync's dry-run as below.

```
rsync -ravun --delete {source} {destination} |grep "^deleting "
```

**From man rsync :**

u - skip files that are newer on the receiver

n - perform a trial run with no changes made

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/stat.1) to get information about specific files instead of `ls`. `stat` output is more customizable, since it accepts a format string:

```
$ stat -c '%s %y %n' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
82346 2017-01-03 19:26:17.799547336 +0900 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
$ stat -c '%s %Y %n' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
82346 1483439177 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

`%y` and `%Y` are the last modification times, the former the Unix timestamp, the latter human-readable. For simply processing the information in a script, `%y` is more convenient.

To get the behaviour of `-t`, you can `sort` the output (on the second field `-k2,2`, numerically `-n`, in reverse `-r`):

```
stat -c '%s %y %n' | sort -rnk2,2
```

(I'm assuming that you don't have newlines in your filenames or paths, which I guess is a safe assumption for logs - but if you do, `stat`'s `--printf` option lets you create nul-delimited output, which `sort` can handle fine with `-z`.)